# Chosen values on X axis LineChart

Tags: java, user-interface, charts, jfreechart

I make a JFreeChart from ChartFactory and I put a lot of values to it by calling method: categoryDataset.addValue(...) and then I put categoryDataset to JFreeChart object and that's how I make chart. Due of vast amount of values, my X axis is blurred: [image]

As you can see there are no key values on axis cause there are too many of them. I would like to print on it like only a few values (every 10% interval) so it's readable.

Any advice would be appreciated :)

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.